# How to pass Multipart file from one service to another service in Nodejs without loading into memory

Tags: node.js, nestjs, multipartform-data

How to pass multipart-form data file from one service to another service in Nestjs without loading into memory

So,
I have a proxy server which receive file in multipart-form data and pass on to another api in multipart-form data.
This cause memory spike and cpu utilization at proxy.

How shall I approach this?
can I stream the multipart?

I have tried using Multer, which waits for complete file to arrive and then sends

Comment: Don't parse the body at all, just pipe its stream into the request to the other server.

Comment: Could you please tell how to do that?